# Dynamically set logical fonts for BIRT Charts using Java AWT

Tags: java, birt

I'm using BIRT (v3.7.2) as a reporting tool and have recently migrated it to a linux server.

BIRT generates charts using Java AWT and from what I've read online, Java AWT only supports the 5 logical fonts defined by fontconfig.properties files in jre/lib folders. I have designed my charts using the Arial font, and it seems that Lucida is the default on linux.

I'm unable to sudo to root on this linux server (can't edit the fontconfig.properties file) and I do not wish to make a local copy of java instance just to edit the fontconfig.properties. (last resort...)

I tried using JAVA_FONTS env variable to point to my fonts directory containing Arial, but it doesn't seem to work... (seems like AWT is really stubborn)

Wondering if there's any other method to set the logical fonts for Java dynamically?

Comment: Did you get this fixed anyways ?? I'm facing the same issue

Comment: well, i resorted to the last resort :)